# how to remove query string from subdomain using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a domain (example.com) i created a subdomain for the domain (sub.example).
i have php file in 'dir' folder in the subdomain director.
i need to change url

```
http://sub.example.com/dir/view.php?id=10
```

to

```
http://sub.example.com/dir/view.php/id/10
```

i how to do this?
where i place my .htaccess file?

i beginer to htaccess 
please help me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your root .htaccess you can have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.+?\.php)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ $1/$2?$3=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Where is this htaccess located and what is your DOCUMENT_ROOT path for subdomain?

Comment: my sub domain in a directory 'test' in the public_html. now i placed htaccess file in public_html

Comment: If sub domain is pointing to `public_html/test/` then htaccess must be placed in there only. Also I believe `dir` is subdirectory of `public_html/test/`?

Comment: place in test still not getting get value in $_GET array. but i am getting full url in $_SERVER. i will parse from that. thank you very much.

Comment: This rule is also working fine for me on my Apache. You just need to make sure that it is placed in right htaccess and htaccess is working.

Comment: Also if this answer helped you solve your problem, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.